# Can an ObjectBox property have multiple annotations?

Tags: objectbox, objectbox-android

ObjectBox [documents](https://docs.objectbox.io/entity-annotations) several annotations that can be applied to and entity's properties. Can one property have multiple annotations?

For example, would this be a valid entity?

```kotlin
@Entity
data class User(
    @Id 
    var id: Long = 0,
    @Index 
    @Unique(onConflict = ConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    var name: String = null,
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a property (and and entity) can have multiple annotations.

Your example with `@Index` and `@Unique` is valid; however, because `@Unique` implies `@Index`, the latter is redundant and can be removed.